# Как подключить библиотеку(opencv) с++ к проекту на андроид используя cmake?

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, native

Добрый день. Возникла сложность с использованием c++ библиотеки в андроид проекте. 
Ранее с нативным кодом в андроид работал только в рамках тестового проекта, без использования сторонних библиотек.
В проекте требуется использовать **только** нативный код на плюсах, без использования jni(только для отладки и вызов java кода из под нативного). В доках opencv есть туториал подключения библиотек, но с использованием ndk-build

Первое что было сделано - [отсюда](https://opencv.org/releases.html) скачал AndroidSDK для OpenCV.
Далее - создал проект в Android Studio 3 с поддержкой c++ кода.
Код на с++ был ранее написан с использованием OpenCV для windows, все работало. Скопировал исходники в папку *project\app\src\main\cpp\* , убрал лишний код, добавил jni вызовы для отладки.

Далее в файле **build.gradle** добавил следующее:

```
android {
...
defaultConfig {
    ...
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions -std=c++11"
            arguments '-DOpenCV_DIR=E:/OpenCV/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni'
        }

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'x86'
        }
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs 'src/main/jniLibs/'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
```

В папку *src\main\jniLibs\* скопировал содержимое папки *OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\libs\*

Переходим к файлу **CMakeLists.txt**. Были добавлены следующие строки:

```
add_library( native-lib
             SHARED
             сорцы.cpp )

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries( native-lib
                   src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so )

include_directories( E:/OpenCV/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include )
```

И на конец, в переменные среды был добавлен путь до *%OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK%\sdk\native\jni*

Возникает следующая проблема:
При сборке проекта возникают ошибки:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-
bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake
Error:error: undefined reference to 'cv::boundingRect(cv::_InputArray const&)'
Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Error:org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: Build command failed.
Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Error:Build command failed.
```

И таких **undefined reference** очень много, ругается не только на мои сорцы, но и на .h-файлы opencv. Логика подсказывает, что библиотека не подключилась к проекту.
Подскажите, верный ли путь я проделал для подключения библиотеки, может что-то упустил или сделал в корне не верно?
В проекте картина выглядит следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно, ответ нашел самостоятельно. Неверно был написан файл CMakeLists. 
Ответ нашел [тут](https://github.com/leadrien/opencv_native_androidstudio), сделал все как в этом проекте. Проект собрался.